# My booting speed went from 8 seconds to 30 seconds

Tags: 14.04, boot, lenovo

My booting speed went from 8 seconds to 30 seconds. I don't really know what happened. Any help please ! 
This is my dmseg
http://paste.ubuntu.com/9062894/

and this is my bootchart

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [hostingpics.net](https://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/523927ubuntutrusty201411182.png))</sub>

Comment: What did you do when it changed?  Had you installed or reconfigured any software. What type of hard drive is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things I've noticed from the boot chart:

The bottleneck seems to be disk utilisation. You may have a slow hard disk.

ureadahead is taking a long time to run while waiting for I/O.  This indicates hard disk speed is a factor.